# IPython defaults for pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, ipython

I have the following snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.width', 165)
```

on my startup file:

```
/Users/avazquez/.ipython/profile_default/startup/00-first.py
```

I can see that importing pandas worked (`pd` is already defined when I start IPython). However, the command `pd.set_option('display.width', 165)` didn't work (it does work though if I invoke it manually once IPython has started).

It could be a bug, but I wanted to check here just in case. How can I change my defaults for pandas for IPython?

This is with `IPython 4.0.0` on `Python 3.4.3 :: Anaconda 2.1.0 (x86_64)`.

Answer (score 0):

The below works for IPython 3.x.  For IPython 4.x, there is the issue that [Jupyter does not have profiles](http://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/migrating.html#profiles).

I download a version of ipython, ipython-notebook and qtconsole for each conda environment that I create.

```
$ source activate my_env_name
$ conda install ipython ipython-notebook qtconsole
```

Your can create a [profile](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/intro.html) for iPython within your environment:

```
$ ipython profile create my_profile_name
```

It will tell you where it creates the config files.  If you don’t specify a profile name, IPython always runs in the default profile.

Then go to `.../ipython_config.py` and amend the top of the file as follows:

```
c = get_config()
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ["%run path_to_startup.py"]
```

Where `path_to_startup.py` is the file location of your startup script.

Launch iPython in your given environment with your profile via:

```
$ ipython qtconsole --profile=my_profile_name
```

Note that `qtconsole` is optional.  It should launch with your new settings.